# Twitter authentication URL

Tags: api, authentication, twitter, token

Which URL I should user for authentication user in the Twitter? 
For example, in the Instagram token for user can be received when user click on the following link

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=XXX&response_type=XXX
```

After this its return token and I can work with user profile.

How to build such link for twitter?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API has several ways to authorize and it depends on what you want to do for determining which approach to take.

The OAuth2 approach that instagram takes is called application-only in Twitter API. The thing about application-only is that you can only use it on endpoints that aren't associated with a user. e.g. it's great for search, but doesn't work well for tweeting (which is something a user would do).

A couple other approaches are Single User Authorization, which is good if your app only needs one set of credentials. e.g. a server app. Another is Pin Authorization which is a work-around for devices that can't manage Web callbacks. These use OAuth 1.0A.

There are a few other OAuth options, but this was just to give you an idea about the available choices and the need to think about what you want to accomplish and match that with what the Twitter API offers. Here's the Twitter docs for more info:

[Authentication and Authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth)